# Need help identifying matching recordset in sql

Tags: sql, oracle, matching, recordset

I am doing some remapping of an already setup business and need to do the below in SQL for Oracle 11.

It is a "one time activity" (not a deliverable to my client) and so i was planning not to implement it using a programming language. 
I have the below table. DDL and DML for setup are below.

```
subsriber_cd | prod_id | rate plan | charge_ID | QoS_1  | QoS_2  | QoS_3  | RatePerUnit |
-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-------------| 
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 100       | Credit | Analog |        | 0.1         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 100       | Credit | GSM    |        | 0.2         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 100       | Credit | LTE    |        | 0.3         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 100       | Debit  | Analog |        | 1.1         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 1.2         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 1.3         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 101       | Credit | Analog |        | 2.1         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 101       | Credit | GSM    |        | 2.2         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 101       | Credit | LTE    |        | 2.3         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 101       | Debit  | Analog |        | 3.1         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 3.2         |
pete         | 1       | RP1       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 3.3         |

chris        | 2       | RP2       | 100       | Credit | Analog |        | 5.1         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 100       | Credit | GSM    |        | 5.2         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 100       | Credit | LTE    |        | 5.3         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 100       | Debit  | Analog |        | 6.1         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 6.2         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 6.3         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 101       | Credit | Analog |        | 7.1         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 101       | Credit | GSM    |        | 7.2         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 101       | Credit | LTE    |        | 7.3         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 101       | Debit  | Analog |        | 8.1         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 8.2         |
chris        | 2       | RP2       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 8.3         |

jack         | 3       | RP3       | 100       | Credit | Analog |        | 0.1         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 100       | Credit | GSM    |        | 0.2         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 100       | Credit | LTE    |        | 0.3         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 100       | Debit  | Analog |        | 1.1         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 1.2         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 1.3         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 101       | Credit | Analog |        | 2.1         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 101       | Credit | GSM    |        | 2.2         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 101       | Credit | LTE    |        | 2.3         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 101       | Debit  | Analog |        | 3.1         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 3.2         |
jack         | 3       | RP3       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 3.3         |

...                                                                                      

dave         | 4       | RP4       | 100       | Credit | Analog |        | 10.1        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 100       | Credit | GSM    |        | 10.2        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 100       | Credit | LTE    |        | 10.3        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 100       | Debit  | Analog |        | 10.1        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 10.2        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 10.3        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 101       | Credit | Analog |        | 10.1        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 101       | Credit | GSM    |        | 10.2        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 101       | Credit | LTE    |        | 10.3        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 101       | Debit  | Analog |        | 10.1        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    |        | 10.2        |
dave         | 4       | RP4       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    |        | 10.3        |
```

There was a mistake in the design where each subscriber was assigned a unique product. 
This led to several thousands of products in my system now.

As a redesign I was planning not to create separate products per subscriber but instead to create one product and rate plan, and instead add a new QoS_3 that would help me give different RatePerUnits.

Since pete and jack have the same RatePerUnit, i was planning to store the same QoS_3 for both of them. 
So I need to find the record set with the matching RatePerUnit so that i can merge them as one QoS_3.

In the above table i can merge pete's and jack's QoS_3, as they have the same RatePerUnit for all combinations of other fields, making my table.

```
subsriber_cd | prod_id | rate plan | charge_ID | QoS_1  | QoS_2  | QoS_3  | RatePerUnit |
-------------+---------+-----------+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-------------| 
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | Analog | Q_1    | 0.1         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | GSM    | Q_1    | 0.2         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | LTE    | Q_1    | 0.3         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | Analog | Q_1    | 1.1         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_1    | 1.2         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_1    | 1.3         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | Analog | Q_1    | 2.1         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | GSM    | Q_1    | 2.2         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | LTE    | Q_1    | 2.3         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | Analog | Q_1    | 3.1         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_1    | 3.2         |
pete         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_1    | 3.3         |

chris        | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | Analog | Q_2    | 5.1         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | GSM    | Q_2    | 5.2         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | LTE    | Q_2    | 5.3         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | Analog | Q_2    | 6.1         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_2    | 6.2         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_2    | 6.3         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | Analog | Q_2    | 7.1         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | GSM    | Q_2    | 7.2         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | LTE    | Q_2    | 7.3         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | Analog | Q_2    | 8.1         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_2    | 8.2         |
chris        | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_2    | 8.3         |

jack         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | Analog | Q_1    | 0.1         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | GSM    | Q_1    | 0.2         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | LTE    | Q_1    | 0.3         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | Analog | Q_1    | 1.1         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_1    | 1.2         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_1    | 1.3         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | Analog | Q_1    | 2.1         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | GSM    | Q_1    | 2.2         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | LTE    | Q_1    | 2.3         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | Analog | Q_1    | 3.1         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_1    | 3.2         |
jack         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_1    | 3.3         |

...                                                                                  

dave         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | Analog | Q_4    | 10.1        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | GSM    | Q_4    | 10.2        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Credit | LTE    | Q_4    | 10.3        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | Analog | Q_4    | 10.1        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_4    | 10.2        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 100       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_4    | 10.3        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | Analog | Q_4    | 10.1        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | GSM    | Q_4    | 10.2        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Credit | LTE    | Q_4    | 10.3        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | Analog | Q_4    | 10.1        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | GSM    | Q_4    | 10.2        |
dave         | 5       | RP5       | 101       | Debit  | LTE    | Q_4    | 10.3        |
```

You can see the benefit when the user will now not have to enter 12*4 RatePerUnit for pete, chris, jack and dave, but instead enter 12*3 RatePerUnit.

This will make a huge difference with my redesign as there are ~40K records for all my subscribers.

DDL and DMLs

```
CREATE TABLE combination (
    subsriber_cd VARCHAR2(20),
    prod_id NUMBER(5),
    rate_plan VARCHAR2(20),
    charge_id NUMBER(5),
    qos_1  VARCHAR2(20),
    qos_2  VARCHAR2(20),
    qos_3  VARCHAR2(20),
    rateperunit NUMBER(10,2)
);

INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 100, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 0.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 100, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 0.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 100, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 0.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 100, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 1.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 100, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 1.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 100, 'Debit', 'LTE', '', 1.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 101, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 2.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 101, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 2.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 101, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 2.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 101, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 3.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 101, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 3.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('pete', 1, 'RP1', 101, 'Debit', 'LTE', '', 3.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 100, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 5.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 100, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 5.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 100, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 5.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 100, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 6.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 100, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 6.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 100, 'Debit', 'LTE', '', 6.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 101, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 7.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 101, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 7.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 101, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 7.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 101, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 8.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 101, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 8.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('chris', 2, 'RP2', 101, 'Debit', 'LTE', '', 8.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 100, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 0.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 100, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 0.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 100, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 0.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 100, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 1.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 100, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 1.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 100, 'Debit', 'LTE', '', 1.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 101, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 2.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 101, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 2.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 101, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 2.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 101, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 3.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 101, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 3.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('jack', 3, 'RP3', 101, 'Debit', 'LTE', '', 3.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 100, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 10.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 100, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 10.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 100, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 10.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 100, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 10.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 100, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 10.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 100, 'Debit', 'LTE', '', 10.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 101, 'Credit', 'Analog', '', 10.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 101, 'Credit', 'GSM', '', 10.2);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 101, 'Credit', 'LTE', '', 10.3);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 101, 'Debit', 'Analog', '', 10.1);
INSERT INTO combination
     VALUES ('dave', 4, 'RP4', 101, 'Debit', 'GSM', '', 10.2);
INSERT INTO combination
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you want to update `QOS_3` based on same `rateperunit`. This merge does it:

```
merge into combination c1
using (
  select row_number() over (order by rpu) rn, rpu
    from (
      select rateperunit rpu
        from combination
        group by rateperunit) 
  ) c2
on (c1.rateperunit = c2.rpu)
when matched then update set c1.qos_3 = 'Q_'||lpad(c2.rn, 4, '0')
```

Results:

```
select * from combination order by qos_3

pete   1   RP1   100     Credit   Analog   Q_0001   0.1
jack   3   RP3   100     Credit   Analog   Q_0001   0.1
pete   1   RP1   100     Credit   GSM      Q_0002   0.2
jack   3   RP3   100     Credit   GSM      Q_0002   0.2
pete   1   RP1   100     Credit   LTE      Q_0003   0.3
jack   3   RP3   100     Credit   LTE      Q_0003   0.3
...
dave   4   RP4   101   Credit     GSM      Q_0026  10.2
dave   4   RP4   101   Credit     LTE      Q_0027  10.3
dave   4   RP4   100   Credit     LTE      Q_0027  10.3
dave   4   RP4   100   Debit      LTE      Q_0027  10.3
```